# How to draw shape inside another shape in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have to draw a triangle with a plus sign at the centroid.

I have tried with

```
<Path StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Green" Fill="Green">
    <Path.Data>
       <GeometryGroup Children="{Binding Geometry}"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Geometry collection, one to draw triangle and another to draw a plus. The plus sign is not shown as the fill doesn't have transparency.

I also tried with Combined Geometry, which didn't give what was needed.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: That depends on how you created the plus sign. Is it just two crossed lines, or an outline with a "fillable" interior? In the first case, you could just select some Stroke other than Green. In the second case you should set an appropriate GeometryCombineMode of the CombinedGeometry.

Comment: The plus sign is just two linesegments.

Comment: Then green stroke on green fill doesn't make much sense, right?

Comment: But I have to give color to the triangle. How can I achieve without fill?

Comment: Try `Stroke="Black"` to see what I mean.